# Silencing (not placating) Yarn's "no license field" warning

Tags: yarnpkg

How can I deliberately silence Yarn's "No license field" and "License should be a valid SPDX license expression" warnings, globally across my OS?

I **don't** want to add `private: true` to my `package.json`, nor add a `license` field – I just want to silence Yarn's warnings.